# scala - using filter with pattern matching

Tags: scala, design-patterns, filtering

I have the following lists :

```
case class myPair(ids:Int,vals:Int)

val someTable = List((20,30), (89,90), (40,65), (45,75), (35,45))

val someList:List[myPair] =
  someTable.map(elem => myPair(elem._1, elem._2)).toList
```

I would like to filter  all "ids" > 45 . 
I tried something like this article [filter using pattern matching](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2011/07/12/scala-pattern-matching-a-pair-inside-mapfilter/)):

```
someList.filter{ case(myPair) => ids >= 45 }
```

but without success. 
appreciate your help

Comment: scala> someList.filter{ case(myPair) => myPair.ids >= 45 }
res1: List[myPair] = List(myPair(89,90), myPair(45,75))
(but Answer from Tomasz Nurkeiviecz is better, off course)

Comment: @twillouer: I appreciate your edit but please add a separate answer so you can get a full credit for it.

Comment: You can simplify your `map` call: `someTable.map(myPair.tupled).toList`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't need pattern matching at all, type is known at compile time:

```
someList.filter(_.ids >= 45)
```

or slightly more verbose/readable:

```
someList.filter(pair => pair.ids >= 45)
```

Comment: Thanks, simple and efficient

Answer (score 7):

You mean like:

```
someList.filter{ case MyPair(ids,vals) => ids >= 45 }
```

Renamed `myPair` to `MyPair`, identifiers beginning with lowercase are considered variables, much like `ids` and `vals` in the above.  --Actually this is not true, look at @RandallSchulz's comment.

Going further(1):

```
val someList = someTable.map(case (ids,vals) => MyPair(ids,vals)).toList
```

Even more(2):

```
val someList = someTable.map(elem => MyPair.tupled(elem)).toList
```

Way more(3):

```
val someList = someTable.map(MyPair.tupled).toList
```

Of course, only (1) is about pattern match. (2) and (3) is turning the arguments of `MyPair.apply(Int,Int)` into Tuple[Int,Int].

Comment: Names that start with lower-case are only deemed free pattern variables when they're not followed by an open parenthesis. Nonetheless, any class with an alphanumeric name should start with an upper case letter. On the other hand, if you have, say, a `RegEx` instance and want to match against it (via `RegEx`'s extractor), there's no reason to name it starting with an upper-case letter.

Comment: Yeah, I almost looked for it in the ref... Thanks for the explanation, @RandallSchulz

Comment: If the arguments you have to provide are tuples why not turning your function into `.tupled` instead of turning the tuple into individual values? This is the most concise version of them all `map(MyPair.tupled)`

Comment: @pedrofurla I think for (1) you mean `val someList = someTable.map { case (ids,vals) => MyPair(ids,vals) }.toList`

Answer (score 6):

Here's one more variant using pattern matching

```
someTable collect {case (i, v) if i > 45 => MyPair(i, v)}
```

collect combines a filter operation and a map operation.

Comment: Thanks, that is interesting , because here actually one does not need the use of MyPair and use it simply like this : 
'someTable collect {case (i, v) if i > 45 => MyPair(i, v)}'

Answer (score 0):

```
case class myPair(ids:Int,vals:Int)

val someTable = List((20,30), (89,90), (40,65), (45,75), (35,45))

val someList:List[myPair] = for( elem <- someTable; if elem._1 > 45) yield myPair(elem._1, elem._2)
```

Which gives

```
someList: List[myPair] = List(myPair(89,90))
```